# Second derivative of a homogeneous function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

My math teacher told the following statement: 'A homogeneous polynomial $f(x,y)$ of degree 'n' represents 'n' straight lines passing through the origin, and hence, $\frac d{dx}f(x,y)$ = $\frac yx$, and $\frac {d^2(f(x))}{dx^2}$ = 0'

I could convince myself of the statement by taking an example, $x^3 - 6x^2y + 11xy^2 - 6y^3 = 0$, and plotting it out. But I am unable to generalize it for any *n$^{th}$* degree homogeneous polynomial. It would be great if I could get a proof generalized for any polynomial of degree n (assuming that the polynomial has real, linear factors.) Thanks!

Comment: The statement may not be true if only real lines are under consideration. An $n$ degree polynomial has $n$ complex roots, but not necessarily $n$ real roots. Consider for example the equation:$y^2+xy+5x^2=0$ This has no real lines.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Ritam_Dasgupta! I forgot to mention that the *n$^{th}$* degree polynomial *does* have *n* linear factors and that the lines can be plotted on a graph. Edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Divide the equation by $x^n$ and introduce $k=\frac yx$. We get a polynomial in one variable $k$. If this has $n$ linear factors then we have $n$ roots for $k$, meaning $n$ lines